# How to find the index in a list of numbers where there are repeating numbers

Tags: indexing, python-3.6

For example,

I have a list of numbers

```
[0,1,4,6,4,6,4,4]
```

I want to print the index of 4 and there are several 4's.

The output I want to get is

```
(2,4,6,7)
```

However, when I just use the index function now, it's only giving me the index function of the first "4".